# how to make a random text string csv comform with python?

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

I have a string, which is a text, is has several `\n` and special chars like `<>?;.,`

how to make this string fit into one line when I write it to a cvs file (or other file)?

I want this string to be in one line

Comment: remove all the newlines?

Comment: is there a command for it? I just know strip but it removees only the outer ones or?

Comment: @gurehbgui it's `your_string.replace('\n', '')` ...

Comment: `for line in fin: fout.write(line.rstrip('\n'))` I don't understand your file though...

Comment: @gurehbgui Um that's okay, I'd rather know what this is for before I post an answer, anyone else can feel free to

Comment: If you want to keep the newline information within the string but still want to write it into a csv-file, encode it somehow (base64 for instance).

Comment: Embedded newlines in a CSV value are usually perfectly fine, as long as they're quoted properly. (The `csv` module should Do The Right Thing for you.)

Comment: I did it with the encoding into base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by doing the following:

```
base64.b64encode(my_text)
```

and then write it to the file.